# If-statement with div margin-top as condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, jquery-animate

I'd like to create an if - else condition system which allows scrolling up only when the top margin is different than 0. I'll use the .animate action in jquery to create an animation.

```
$('#up-arrow a').click(function(){
    if('#slider'.css(margin-top)!='0px')
        $('#slider').animate({'margin-top':'+=320px'});
    else
```

Can someone please correct this for me? It works without the if, but after I added the if-else it does nothing.

Comment: Hint: `if('#slider'.css(margin-top)!='0px')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this

```
if('#slider'.css(margin-top)!='0px')
```

Try this

```
if($('#slider').css("margin-top")!='0px')
```

Answer (score 2):

If else statements require curly braces. If statements with a single expression may be written without curly braces but this practice is usually advised against.

Try this:

```
$('#up-arrow a').click(function(){
    if($('#slider').css("margin-top")!='0px') {
        $('#slider').animate({'margin-top':'+=320px'});
    } else {
        //whatever you want to do here...
    }
});
```

Comment: "usually advised agaist" - pfft, I do this all the time.  Though I did waste an hour once after screwing this up...so maybe this is good advice... +1 :)

Comment: lol :) Mostly it's harmless but occasionally it causes exceptionally hard to find bugs. Personally I just don't like how it looks